# Problem with reCAPTCHA - ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

Tags: gwt, localhost, recaptcha

I'm sure my API keys are correct and my domain is checked.

I use `127.0.0.1` as a domain to develop every state of reCAPTCHA.
reCAPTCHA returns 0.9 and I set `threshold = 0.99` to test the reCAPTCHA,
but it shows me every time this ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type.

It seems to be a problem with reCAPTCHA.js.
I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that. It is necessary to execute reCAPTCHA by the version 3 sitekey, and render reCAPTCHA by the version 2 sitekey.